# Likelihood calculation w.r.t. uniform discrete distributions

Tags: maximum-likelihood, interpretation, likelihood, uniform-distribution

I am working on a little project where I use observations to infer a hidden parameter in Pokemon battling. Without delving into the the mechanics too much, I will attempt to describe the context of the problem.

You are trying to infer the attack stat of an opposing Pokemon based on the damage it inflicts to yours. The damage is a function of many parameters, but most (your hp, defense stat, base power of the attack) are known to you. The only unknowns are their attack and the integer $r \in [0, 15]$ that determine the damage like so
$$\text{ damage } = \lfloor k \cdot \theta \cdot (\frac{85 + r}{100}) \rfloor$$
where $k$ is just the collapsing of the other known parameters and $\theta$ is our opponents attack stat (the parameter of interest).

Thus the 'damage rolls' are typically a uniform distribution on $[.85D, D]$ where $D = k \cdot \theta$ is the max damage roll. However there are often gaps between the rolls, with some integers not included. Also it is possible with really low damage that different values of $r$ may yield identical damage. However for the sake of simplicity lets just assume that the numbers are high enough that each $r$ produces a unique damage amount.

So lets say we observe damage values $d_1, ..., d_n$ from our opponents attack. It is now not clear to me what the correct notion of likelihood is. If a specific value of $\theta$ is able to produce the observed damage rolls, then naively the likelihood should be $\frac{1}{16}^n$. This is invariant w.r.t. $\theta$...

Intuitively there should be some consideration of the distance from the mean damage roll. I considered the likelihood as something like (this exact formula assigns 0 likelihood for a max roll)
$$ \prod (1 - \frac{|r_i - 7.5|}{7.5}) $$
where $r_i$ is the unique uniform random that corresponds to $d_i$
In this vein I've also considered treating this as a minimization problem where I try to find $\theta$ that minimizes the term $\sum (r_i - 7.5)^2$. I'm certain I should be working with $r_i$ and not $d_i$

However lately I think the real answer is to consider the average observed $r_i$, call it $\bar{\mu}$, and letting $N(\bar{\mu})$ be the likelihood where $N$ is the pdf of the appropriate normal distribution.

And of course there is the case where different $r$ can yield the same observed damage.